# How to show a JDialog of a parser tree in antlr4.5.1?

Tags: java, antlr4

I want the system to pop up a dialog to show the parser tree. I want to know if there is a function to invoke in Java so I can do the thing above and I know at version 4.3 antlr got a function in class RuleContext named inspect to pop up a JDialog.

Comment: You might want to show us your code - what you've already tried.

Comment: I haven't done much yet and now I'm just wondering if there is a function to pop up a JDialog showing the parser tree based on my grammar file *.g4 at antlr 4.5.1? The programme can parse the giving input sentence but now I want it to show the parser tree. Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when updating to the latest Antlr 4 version. The `inspect` method can now be found in the `Trees` class, as of [this commit](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/commit/b395127e733b33c27f344695ebf155ecf5edeeab).